# Dynamically changing directive attributes in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, templates, binding, angularjs-directive

Need a bit of help to get this to finished it off. But if someone has a better suggestion I am an open minded individual.

Basically I've written a directive to swap out templates based on directive attribute.

```
<div id="popup" class="popup my-directive" type="player" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Problem that I have is changing the `type` attribute such that it would trigger `$digest` and re-evaluate my directive.

```
$scope.selectTeam = function () {
    $scope.type = 'team';
    //$scope.$apply(function () {
    // bind directive
    $(".popup").attr("type", "team");
    // show popup div
    $(".popup").show();
    //});
};
```

The purpose of `type` attribute is to track which template will be bound to `popup` div.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC', // Attribute, Element, Class
        transclude: true, // expose controller scope
        templateUrl: function(element, attr){
            var type = typeof attr.type !== 'undefined' ? attr.type : 'player';

            if(!type) return;

            return 'search-' + type + '-tpl.html';
        },
    }
});
```

For live example please have a look at my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/szI7zThICfUjeIhceiOp?p=preview).

I will now try something with `$compile` to build my `popup` with new `type` value in each select function but really don't fancy this approach.

#### update

OK, I have cracked it quicker than originally expected. Live [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Y8AkFabdTgSUFFQ1OY6?p=preview).

Changes I introduced to controller:

```
$scope.selectTeam = function () {
    $scope.type = 'team'; // trigers $digest
    $(".popup").replaceWith($compile(angular.element(document).find("my-directive").attr("type", "team"))($scope));
    $(".popup").show();
};
```

Changes I introduced to HTML:

```
<my-directive id="popup" class="popup" type="player" style="display: none;"></my-directive>
```

The only issue this present that I noticed is `Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` when I try to search. But I can live with this.

As I mentioned before if someone has a different idea/approach or noticed something funny in my code please do share.

Comment: I'll try do see what i can do. But in my opinion this is getting really too complicated. Most of the time custom directives are miss-used and can be simply resolved without directive. Can you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to do ? (Functionally, not technically).

Comment: Okey, looke further into your code, i can guess why you've got some complications. You're using some jQuery within angular controller. You should never do that. Could we have a little chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83430/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-31453249-dynamically-changing-directive-attrib ?

Comment: @Okazari certainly I agree with you to a certain point. I am trying to come with a pop-up mechanism for searching and selecting a value from a collection of ``something``. Depending on what this ``something`` is the search and the values may differ. Thats why I went with a directive after I scrapped my ``$compile`` version - http://plnkr.co/edit/JKOYHMdaarUrl4R11dKm?p=preview. While I have used extremely simple examples in my plunkers in reality these search/select pop-ups will be more complicated. I hope this gives a bit of an insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a talk i found out two solutions.

First you can do what you need using ng-include this way instead of creating a custom directive (see it working into this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VhniEHvl8Wd0K0NBOaUG?p=preview)) :

```
<div ng-show="showSelect" ng-include="'search-'+type+'-tpl.html'">
```

Secondly i pointed out that this could be a modal using $modal (using "templateUrl") from ui-boostrap.

I actually tend to prefer the second option as you can define a controller, template, css etc... for each modal which is a bit cleaner and readable.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for having a chat with me. I learned a lot from that.